# Redirection 301 for all urls in a domain

Tags: redirect, heroku, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I have set up a redirection from `example.com` to `www.example.com` for my web site in my domain panel using URL Forwarding with the status of 301. It works fine (it redirects me from  `example.com` to `www.example.com` as expected), but it doesn't do that for the urls like `example.com/some_url` to `www.example.com/some_url` or least to `www.example.com/`.

This site is on heroku and has `cname` pointing to `example.herokuapp.com`, by the way.

How do I make the urls like `example.com/some_url`, `example.com/some_url2`... work properly? I'd like it to be the easiest free approach.

Answer (score 0):

A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page. 301 refers to the HTTP status code for this type of redirect. In most instances, the 301 redirect is the best method for implementing redirects on a website.